# Java Eclipse SVN - Commiting

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I've been using Eclipse and SVN for a very long time now, and this is the first time I think I've seen this bug. I tried to commit my Java project after changing just a few small things. I get this error:

```
Error while dispatching event: org.eclipse.team.svn.core.connector.ISVNProgressMonitor.reportError(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: It appears to be a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293588). Try updating.

Comment: updating Eclipse? or SVN? or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be Subversive, and not Eclipse. [Dupe bug that vcsjones posted.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300800#c2)

If you are using Subversive, I'd recommend Subclipse. It works much better from personal experience.

Comment: do I need to uninstall subversive? how will eclipse know to use subclipse for my svn work?

Comment: You might need to delete your project and re-download it from the repository using Subclipse. After that, it will be fine. The only problem with having both Subclipse and Subversion installed simultaneously is that SVN may displayed twice in places, which can be confusing.

Comment: I made the mistake of installing both of them. It's unfortunate now because I have 2 SVN option tabs and perspectives, each different as Chris pointed out. In order for me to have Eclipse ignore subversive I uninstalled it's svn connectors. However, I'm running on a 64-bit system so you have to get the proper java-HL svn connector from sliksvn for subclipse to work. You may also need TortoiseSVN.